# Tor browser does not load angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, tor

I have written a web application which is using `AngularJS v1.6.4` and `angular-google-maps 2.4.1 2017-01-05`.

I have tested with *Microsoft Edge*, *Google Chrome*, *Mozilla Firefox* and everything was fine.

---

But, when trying to view my app in the *Tor browser*, it does not load correctly, even though the developer console (F12) does not show any errors.

Is it because of the following code (get user location through *GeoIP*) which mismatches the Tor policy?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://www.freegeoip.net/xml");
XmlNodeList nodeLstLatitude = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Latitude");
visitor.ipLatitude = nodeLstLatitude[0].InnerText;

XmlNodeList nodeLstLongitude = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Longitude");
visitor.ipLongitude = nodeLstLongitude[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Tor has JavaScript disabled by default according to their FAQ, so it's not angular specific.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript is disabled (or at least not *fully* enabled) by default, to prevent *Browser fingerprinting*.**

It does allow some javascript though, because most sites need it to function.

You can probably run an Angular app just fine by enabling all sort of javascript stuff in Tor's settings panel, *but nobody will do this.*

Because of Angular's core wrappers such as `$document` and `$window`, and the use of local storage through `$templateCache` and `$localStorage` (when installed), it will probably never run on Tor's default settings.

---

*Browser* or *Device Fingerprinting* is used to create profile from a visitor by gathering specific information such as device resolution, browser version, etc.

You can see for yourself if you type `navigator` or `window` into the Chrome console, and this is just a fraction of things Javascript can track.

This means, that you can identify returning visits from a user, even if you log out, clear your cache and cookies, switch IP every visit (Tor), etc. This is not what you want when using Tor.

For more info see the wiki entry for [Device Finterprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint), or this [in-depth paper](https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf) on the subject.

Comment: @@Jeffrey Thank you for answer, So there is no other way to render it. I have function which find user`s location and if they used proxy, I will get default ip which is not their ip, according what you said about hidden navigation , if I remove "freegeoip" can I load the rest of anguglarjs?

Comment: GeoIP can be run server side (recommended), so you can still use it when removing it from your app. As for AngularJs, it uses wrappers for document (`$document`), window (`$window`), etc, which can be used for fingerprinting. Since these are part of Angular's core, I doubt you can switch those off.

Comment: @@Jeffrey  Is "<!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie9"><![endif]-->" a way to check if Tor supports angular? what should I write instead of class="lt-ie9"?

Comment: I know that the *Tor browser* is actually *Firefox* behind the scenes. I doubt you can get stuff working by using *internet Explorer* specific classes, but who knows. As mentioned, I think Angular will probably never function correctly with the default Tor settings, because of it's core wrappers. Maybe you can try to find some online demo's (or create some yourself) of older Angularjs versions and check them in Tor. Maybe they do work, and you can think about using an older version of Angular!

Answer (score 0):

Tor browser is not designed to develop complex angular apps on. However if your target is the tor browser then javascript is disabled by default, if you are familiar with firefox, enabling/ disabling JS is the same as firefox as the tor browser is built on FF.
Enabling it is trivial if you just look through the settings.

Comment: I used F12 , I can see "Inspector", "Console" , "Debugger" sections. In debugger -> sources -> "This page has o sources". I am new on "Tor" , is there any addins or something which should I add?